# User definable field labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rais app. Two models, Account and User, with multiple users in each account.

I would like to have 5 fields against a user, and would like someone at the account level to define the field labels so that they always appear the same and are custom for each account.

So the way I am thinking at the moment is to create 5 fields on the user to contain the data, and 5 fields on the account to store the labels.

Does this sound sensible?

Forgive the basic question, but I don't want to do something stupid here in case 5 fields turns into 10 fields...

Comment: Employee refers to user?  Also, I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do.  Is the account model acting like a site admin?  Will one account set one user's labels?  Or will all accounts set some users labels?  Or all users labels?  Can you describe with some more detail what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a model LabelContainer with those 5 fields as strings (and one integer field for `user_id`), and put `has_one :label_container` relationship in User model (and `belongs_to :user` in LabelContainer model). 
Then in your labels access those fields like `@user.label_container.field_one`

Hope, that's enough clear.